# Plot a 3D-plane in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I plot a 3D-plane at specific point in Matlab?

Consider the plane equation

```
Z=(-a * X - b * Y)/c
```

with following coefficients:

```
a=0.01; b=0.03; c= 1; d=0.
```

I want to plot this plane around point (100,100) not at origin (0,0). How it possible to do that?

The code I used:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
a=0.1;
b=0.2;
c=1;
d=0;
Z=(-a * X - b * Y)/c;
surf(X,Y,Z)
shading flat
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

Comment: You mean you want to plot it around X=100 and Y=100? In what range?

Comment: If you you plate a 3D plane in matlab, the center of the plane will be at (0,0,0) by default. I want to make the center of the plane at (100,100,0) rather than (0,0,0).

Comment: You mean "plot", right? I'm not aware of such a default. Could you please include code to show what you are referring to?

Comment: [X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
a=0.1; b=0.2; c= 1; d=0;
Z=(-a * X - b * Y)/c;
surf(X,Y,Z)
shading flat
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');

Comment: Thanks. Using `meshgrid`, the range of `X` and `Y` is determined by the values in `x`. How is `x` defined? – Please include additional information in the question itself, not in a comment. Use the "edit" button below the question text.

Comment: The question about `x`? I think that's the crucial point here. – Edited your question for better formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`surf()` just plots whatever set of points you give it. To generate those points, you're evaluating the equation at a specific set of coordinates given by `X` and `Y`. Therefore you want those points to be centred around the region of interest:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(95:0.1:105);  % e.g. +/-5 at resolution of 0.1
```

or, say, for arbitrary view coordinates `m`,`n`:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(m-20:m+20, n-20:n+20);  % e.g. +/-20 at resolution of 1
```

That gives you the view around 100,100 of a plane centred at the origin, which I think is what you're asking for.

Alternatively if you want the plane *itself* centred at 100,100, then you need that offset in the equation:

```
Z=(-a * (X - 100) - b * (Y - 100))/c;
```

so then a view centred on the origin will be equivalent to viewing the original plane around -100,-100.