# MATLAB plot plane equation

Tags: matlab

I have the following plane equation `Yhat = 1.2 + 2.1*A + 3.1*B` extracted from a multiple linear regression model with two continuous predictors variables A and B, and the predicted variable Yhat. All variables are continuous and have values between 1 and 10.

How can I plot this plane equation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a 3D-plane in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063379/plot-a-3d-plane-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy.

Create A and B in the required range using meshgrid

```
[A,B]=meshgrid(1:10,1:10);
```

evaluate the equation

```
Yhat = 1.2 + 2.1.*A + 3.1.*B;
```

and use the surf function

```
surf(A,B,Yhat)
```

[image]